# How to dismiss multiple sheets in SwiftUI with one animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you dismiss multiple SwiftUI sheets in one animation?

Here is an example where I have multiple sheets displayed. This works to dismiss them both but the first will slide down and then the second one will slide down in a separate animation. I want them all to slide down at the same time.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showMainSheet = false
    @State var showDetailSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Main Sheet") {
                showMainSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showMainSheet) {
            Button("Show Detail Sheet") {
                showDetailSheet = true
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetailSheet) {
                Button("Dismiss All") {
                    showDetailSheet = false
                    showMainSheet = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the sheets. That works for me:

```
    import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showMainSheet = false
    @State var showDetailSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Main Sheet") {
                showMainSheet = true
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetailSheet) {
            Button("Dismiss All") {
                showDetailSheet = false
                // this delay ensures that you still see both sheets disappear separately
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    showMainSheet = false
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showMainSheet) {
            Button("Show Detail Sheet") {
                showDetailSheet = true
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of works but then you lose the presenting animation for the detail sheet.

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding a delay so you still get (some sort of) animation of the detail sheet. 
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    showMainSheet = false
                }